# Amazon AWS connection error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have just setup my first Redshift cluster and attempting to connect to it via SQL Workbench to be able to create tables.

I have followed the directions for installing and configuring SQL Workbench here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html

I have also downloaded and configured both the 4.0 and 4.1 version of the Redshift JDBC driver and attempted to use both.

When I configure a connection using the JDBC URL provided in the cluster configuration, the SQL Workbench attempts to connect and then I receive the following error:

> Amazon(500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection timed out:
>   connect.

Comment: Please describe your security group settings.

Comment: Most likely related to the Security Group not permitting access and/or the cluster not being in a Public Subnet of your VPC.

Answer (score 3):

1. go to to EC2 Console=>Security group  , edit the inbound rule add Redshift  Select Source MYIP , It will be autofilled by your IP[CIDR]
2. tried to connect to Redshift using JDBC URL/SQL WORKBENCH Issue  is not resolved  , Later I disconnected from corporate LAN and used my personal WI FI Network  to connect to Internet.
3. go to to EC2 Console=>Security group  , edit the inbound rule add Redshift  Select Source MYIP , It will be autofilled by your IP[CIDR] , your CIDR will not be same as in step-1
4. now my connection with REDSHIFT  using JDBC URL/SQL WORKBENCH is working fine.

Looks Issue is because of Proxy setting of corporate LAN.

Comment: I also got this error as a result of a closed port in the security group.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if there is any proxy that you need to configure(if you are connecting from a secured network). I had the same issue while i was trying to connect to AWS and setting proxy, proper credentials solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be because of various reasons.

Generally connection timed out occurs if you instance is unreachable.

If you machine is inside a VPC, please check if it is in a private or public subnet.

Please check your NACL/Security group settings.

Please check if you have selected require_ssl to true in the DB parameter groups which will also cause you error while accessing using the SQL Workbench

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs also because IP ranges that your DB administrator has configured to be serviced by AWS cluster. I had this same issue and it turned out that my IP address was not a participant of the IP ranges set by my DB admin. He added my IP and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to replace the hostname in the JDBC URL with the public IP of the cluster, that worked for me!

Comment: Where can I get the public IP of redshift cluster?

Comment: In the cluster details. Node IP addresses in the right bottom.

Comment: or an internal IP in some cases. e.g, your vpn is configures so that urls can be resolved to internal ips

Answer (score 0):

This happens only if you are using other port number apart from 8192. Change the port number to 8192 and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below workaround and it worked.

1. Ensure you have the right security group with valid port defined
2. **Under "Network and security", set the "Publicly accessible" value "Yes"**
3. Follow the SqlWorkbench/J https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html
4. To play around with table creation and data handling, follow the steps given in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-data.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.