# Amazon Redshift 500150 Error setting connection: Connection timed out: connect - SQL Workbench/J

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc, sql-workbench-j

I'm trying to connect to my Redshift Cluster by using SQL Workbench/J. Followed all the instructions:

- Downloaded and set Amazon Redshift JDBC 4.2 Driver in the connection profile
- Copy & paste Database JDBC URL
- Set Database Username & pwd
- Created Inbound Rule in my VPC Security Group: Redshift - TCP - 5439 - MyIP

Tested the connection and got the "500150 Error setting connection: Connection timed out: connect" message. I made sure the JDBC URL, the Port and the USR&PWD are correct.

Did some research ([question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933479/redshift-connection-issue-in-sql-workbench-j), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51681182/amazon500150-error-setting-closing-connection-connection-timed-out), [question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788418/amazon-aws-connection-error), [question4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335761/amazon-500150-unable-to-connect-to-redshift-cluster)), and none of the proposed solutions work for me. Any hint?

Comment: Have you tried using a different client? `psql` maybe? Are you sure that your redshift cluster is publically accessible - there's a redshift config controlling that.

Comment: "*Connection timed out: connect*"  typically means the server isn't accessible at all e.g. because of firewall settings

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you were right, the firewall was the issue here. Fixed and working. Thanks both for the help.